# OpenAI Spinning Up: Breakout-v0 example

Tags: reinforcement-learning, open-ai

I haven't been able to find any assistance / examples which could help me implement OpenAI's Spinning Up resource to solve Atari's Breakout-v0 game in the OpenAI gym.

I simply want to know why the following command doesn't run, and instead produces an error that I can't find any help on:

```
python -m spinup.run ppo --env Breakout-v0 --exp_name simpletest
```

...and then the error:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 4 for 'pi/multinomial/Multinomial'
 (op: 'Multinomial') with input shapes: [?,210,160,4], [].
```

I understand the shape dynamics, and have written several (albeit quite unoptimized!) reinforcement learning neural nets in Python, but I was looking forward to using OpenAI's Spinning Up environment to use something more sophisticated and optimized.

Thank you so much for any help on the seeminly noobish question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for anyone struggling to understand the [OpenAI's Spinning Up](https://spinningup.openai.com) educational resource, I'll provide the answer to my question here.

Firstly, it's important to understand that the [algorithms](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/user/algorithms.html) expect a 2-dimensional input **shape**, in rudimentary terms a shape of `Box(int)`, which isn't the case with the default [Breakout-v0](https://gym.openai.com/envs/Breakout-v0/) game environment, which supplies inputs in the shape `Box(210, 160, 3)`, which is the game screen's height, width, and RGB colour space.

The [Breakout-ram-v0](https://gym.openai.com/envs/Breakout-ram-v0/) game environment, however, *DOES* provide an input of the appropriate shape, consequently `Box(128,)`. So switching to this environment solves the initial problem I was having. To train any of the on-policy algorithms ([PPO](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/algorithms/ppo.html) in my case), the command should be:

```
python -m spinup.run ppo --env Breakout-ram-v0 --exp_name simpletest
```

To take this a step further, how would you train an off-policy algorithm (such as [DDPQ](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/algorithms/ddpg.html))? Well, the off-policy algorithms expect a **continuous action space**, which can be seen in the differences in the source code here between [MountainCar-v0](https://gym.openai.com/envs/MountainCar-v0/), and [MountainCarContinuous-v0](https://gym.openai.com/envs/MountainCarContinuous-v0/):

```
self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(3)
```

...versus:

```
self.action_space = spaces.Box(low=self.min_action, high=self.max_action,
    shape=(1,), dtype=np.float32)
```

So, to sum up, how would you train something like the [Lunar Lander](https://gym.openai.com/envs/LunarLander-v2/) game environment with the DDPQ algorithm? Well, you'd need the continuous action space version, and by providing it with 2 dense layers with 192 nodes each, I was able to achieve the following results with just 200 epochs using the following command:

```
python -m spinup.run ddpg --env LunarLanderContinuous-v2 --exp_name ddpq-test --hid [192,192] --epochs 200
```

[image: LunarLanderContinuous-v2 OpenAI DDPQ test]

Pretty cool...anyways, I hope this helps someone sometime, and I would thoroughly recommend looking at the source code for the various OpenAI game environments, as well as their [table of game environments](https://github.com/openai/gym/wiki/Table-of-environments) for a quick reference to the observation and action spaces. Good luck!